# PHP Function and variables stored in a string in a database

Tags: php, string, function, eval

I need to store data within a database, when I get the data from the database I need functions and variables in the string to be worked out as such.

Example

```
$str = "<p>Dear {$this->name},</p>"
```

I then store this in the database, and when I retrieve the string and run it through

```
eval("\$detail= \"$detail\";");
```

then the variable gets populated with the name. This is exactly what I needed and works fine.

The problem is I want to run a function with this variable as the parameter.

example. I would like to `ucwords` the variable.

I have tried:

```
$str = "<p>Dear {ucwords($this->name)},</p>"  //just echoed {ucword(->name)},
$str = "<p>Dear {ucwords($this->name)},</p>"  //Fatal error: Function name must be a string,
```

Am I going in the right direction?
Is this at all possible?

Comment: @hsz `eval()` isn't inherently evil, but it's very easy to misuse/overuse.

Comment: first tim ei have used eval, i couldn't see any other way of having dynamic variables called from database?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to keep PHP code in database. This is a bad practice and also can lead to security vulnerabilities.

Instead store in database string like this:

```
<p>Dear [name],</p>
```

And when you retrieve it you can just do:

```
$stringFromDb = str_replace("[name]", $this->name, $stringFromDb);
```

or

```
$stringFromDb = str_replace("[name]", ucwords($this->name), $stringFromDb);
```

Other common approach is to use `sprintf`. So you need to store in database string with `%s` as placeholders for values.

Example:

```
<p>Dear %s,</p>
```

and replace with

```
$stringFromDb = sprintf($stringFromDb, ucwords($this->name));
```

Comment: Hiya thanks for the reply.
The problem is that i am will be creating a GUI for the database.
This will allow the user to input any variable to be in the string.

My model and related models have many variables

Comment: wow this site is so quick, thanks for the help.

Ok, the issue is i wont know what variables the user have put into the string (email)

Comment: say for eg.
The email could have $this->name, $this->balance, $this->street.

Comment: If you are building UI for your database then definitely you don't want PHP codes there, because it is a total mess. How you would explain to users what kind of variables you have in your code available for evaluation? I would suggest defining list of things that can be inserted into texts (like: [name], [email], [tel], etc) and build combo box with this values and offer convenient way for inserting them into text.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be looking for is a simple templating language.

It's been a long while since I've written PHP (and I suddenly remember why...), but here's something I whipped up.

It should support both objects (`$a->name`) and arrays (`$a["name"]`) as input objects.

You can add new filters (name -> function name mapping) in `$valid_filters`.

```
$valid_filters = array("title" => "ucfirst", "upper" => "strtoupper");

function _apply_template_helper($match) {
  global $_apply_template_data, $valid_filters;
  $var = $match[1];
  $filter = $valid_filters[trim($match[2], ':')];
  $value = is_array($_apply_template_data) ? $_apply_template_data[$var] : $_apply_template_data->$var;
  if($filter && !empty($value)) $value = call_user_func($filter, $value);
  return !empty($value) ? $value : $match[0];
}

function apply_template($template, $data) {
  global $_apply_template_data;
  $_apply_template_data = $data;
  $result = preg_replace_callback('/\{\{(.+?)(:.+?)?\}\}/', "_apply_template_helper", $template);
  $_apply_template_data = null;
  return $result;
}
```

How to use it:

```
$template = "Hello {{name:title}}, you have been selected to win {{amount}}, {{salutation:upper}}";
echo apply_template($template, array("name"=>"john", "amount" => '$500,000', "salutation" => "congratulations"));
```

The result:

> Hello John, you have been selected to win $500,000, CONGRATULATIONS

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following works,

If i contain the function within the class itself then it can be called using the following code

```
<p>Dear {\$this->properCase(\$this->rl_account->name)},</p>
```

But i would like to be able to do this now without having the database have the code as Alex Amiryan mentions earlier.